# How to make a bootable OS X 10.10 Yosemite install Usb drive for Ubuntu using terminal code

Tags: boot, usb, mac, macosx

I have Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite MacPro laptop.

Everywhere, they are telling me to run Etcher, but my OS X 10.10 Yosemite is outdated and this programme is un-installable. Unetbootin also doesn't work. I tried to install it and it told me that it is unmountable.

I need to create bootable USB drive to install Ubuntu. Only way to do this is by using MacOS Terminal and there is no where to find this terminal code. Please help!!!

Comment: This is not the site for Mac support.

Comment: This question is about installing Ubuntu and was specifically addressed in [Ubuntu Help Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Comment: Dear David and Alejandro, Unetbootin doesn't work on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and I am trying to install Ubuntu which is Ubuntu support.

Comment: Hello Ming. do you have CD/DVD drive?

Comment: Hi jpbrain, Yes I think so>.<

Comment: Then just burn the iso file into a blank disk. Can you boot from there?

Comment: Awwww can you really do that??

Comment: But I want to learn from terminal end, I want to keep USB stick handy to boot again if necessary, do you know if my terminal code is correct??

Comment: sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2

Comment: Is this correct???

Comment: Yes. that will work assuming that your usb drive is /dev/disk2.  Be carefull about that, you will delete anything that is on the destination (of).

Comment: @jpbrain is correct that you could also try to burn the ISO image into a DVD and then boot from the DVD by rebooting and holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key as if it were a USB stick.

Comment: Thank you all, I will give them a try>_<

Answer (score 0):

**Preferred method:**

You may want to try [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

**Manual method:**

Alternatively, if Unetbootin does not run under Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, try the following steps:

1. Open **Terminal** and run the following command:

```
diskutil list
```

2. Connect a USB stick with 4 GB or more capacity, then run again:

```
diskutil list
```

3. From the output of both commands, determine the device assigned to your USB stick *(as an example, it may be `/dev/disk2`)*.
4. Run:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

*(Replace **N** with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, **N** would be **2**.)*

5. Run:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/diskN
```

You will need to enter your login password, and it will take some time to complete, so wait patiently.

*(Replace `/path/to/image.iso` with the path to the Ubuntu ISO image you downloaded, e.g. `~/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`, and replace **N** with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, **N** would be **2**.)*

**BE CAREFUL!** The `dd` command will erase the selected disk. Make sure you select the correct disk for `of=/dev/diskN`.

6. Run:

```
diskutil eject /dev/diskN
```

7. Restart your Mac and press and hold <kbd>alt</kbd> while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick (`EFI Boot` option with the USB logo).

[image: Select EFI Boot]

Comment: Hi there, I did (1) diskutil list
(2) diskutil list
(3) diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
(4) sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2  and now it is kind of stuck showing no more text on terminal?!?! I hope I have done this right???

Comment: It says password and I have typed in my normal password to get into MacOS? Is this the right password I should be using???

Comment: When I run Unebootin, it says there is no mountable disk T____T

Comment: The `sudo` command is asking for your normal login password, yes. The `dd` command does take a long time because it has to copy the contents of the image into the USB, it will show a summary of the copy once it finishes. Did you manage to do it or do you need extra help?

Comment: You could try to speed up the `dd` command by adding the option `bs=1m` (or `bs=1M` if that fails) at the end of it. You could try to show the progress of the copying process by adding the option `status=progress`. Example: `sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/diskN bs=1m status=progress`.